# Screen get shrink in iOS 7 when creating project in Xcode 6.1 and later

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, xcode6

I create a new project in **Xcode 6.1** and using Xcode 6 new Feature **"Size Class"**. I target my application to iOS 7.0 but when i run my application on **iOS 7.0 device** its shrink my screen and even constraints are not working correctly as they have to.

And when i run this application in **iOS 8 device** its working perfectly as they have to,
Please see the below Image that show shrink in iOS 7.0

[image]

**If any one have solution for this problem than Please help me out this.**

Answer (score 2):

For iOS7 you still need to provide proper launch image for 4" iPhone, otherwise app will run with black areas.

Answer (score 0):

You probably deleted the launch image. Recreate it in `Images.xcassets`. Click the `+` and choose *New Launch Image*. You can leave it empty.

Another way is to use the new Xcode 6 feature `Launch Screen.xib`.

Comment: you mean to say that because of launch screen my application is behaving like that ? I have not deleted Launch Image and even when i run the application on iOS 7 its Calling black image. and i have no problem with that, the above screen is my application Home screen not a launch screen

Comment: The borders appear when there is no launch image. Did you try my suggestion? Go to the images.xcassets folder, delete the LaunchImage and recreate it. It will be filled with all required solutions. You can leave the images empty, they just need to be there.